# PyQGIS QgsVectorDataProvider unexpected type in argument in method changeGeometryValues

Tags: pyqgis, geometry

When I try to modify a features geometry in a vector layer (linestrings) resulting from a `processing.runalg()` operation like

```
clip = processing.runalg('qgis:clip', ...)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(clip['OUTPUT'], 'TheLayerName', 'ogr')

# add layer to map registry, load named style, create spatial index

layer_dp = layer.dataProvider()

# assume feat is a feature of mem_layer
# assume pt some QgsPoint on feat.geomatry(), but not a vertex

dist, p2, to_id = feat.geometry().closestSegmentWithContext(pt)

# obviously, insertVertex() does not accept QgsPoint as first argument 
newgeom = feat.geometry().insertVertex(pt.x(), pt.y(), to_id)

layer_dp.changeGeometryValues({feat.id() : newgeom})
```

as decribed in the PyQGIS Programming Cookbook 2.18, Section 5.4.3, p.21 (https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/pdf/en/QGIS-2.18-PyQGISDeveloperCookbook-en.pdf)

I get the following error:

> QgsVectorDataProvider.changeGeometryValues(unknown-type): argument 1
>   has unexpected type 'dict'

What can be possibly gone wrong here?

Comment: Can you update your question and show where you are defining newgeom?

Comment: Sorry, it's not about a memory layer, not shure if this is important... I updated my question, hope this is is helpful in the context of this error

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - What do you receive when you `print newgeom`?

Comment: Should mem_layer_dp.changeGeometryValues..... be layer_dp.changeGeometryValues.....?

Comment: that's right...

Comment: How are you defining the feat object?

Comment: @Joseph this pointed me to right direction (again): when I `print newgeom` I receive `True`, so `insertVertex()` obviously does not return the changed geometry, but changes the geometry in-place and returns True, when successful. So, my error message might have lead to slight misinterpretations... Going to add this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The erroneous part in my code is, that the `insertVertex()` method of the `QgsGeometry` class does not return a `QgsGeometry`, but changes the geometry from which it is called in-place, and returns 'True' if the insertion was successful.

So the problem is not the dictionary passed to the `QgsVectorDataProvider.changeGeometryValues({id:geom})` method, but the value being a boolean value instead of a `QgsGeometry`, so the above code works with a small alteration:

```
...
newgeom = feat.geometry()
newgeom.insertVertex(pt.x(), pt.y(), to_id)
...
```